# How to remove tcpdf from Components in Joomla admin panel?

Tags: joomla-3.5, virtuemart

A while ago in this thread here:

https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=126403.0

**GJC Web Design** described the way to get rid of "Virtuemart aio" empty menu item in Joomla's "Components" menu by doing this in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM `jos_menu` WHERE `link` LIKE '%allinone%'
```

Now my question is... what SQL query is necessary to remove "tcpdf" empty entry from Joomla's "Components" menu?

Answer (score 1):

TCPDF can usually be removed using the normal uninstall process in extension manager:

[image: tcpdf]

I don't think there are normally any menu options associated with TCPDF but if there were, these could be removed like this or similar:

```
DELETE FROM `jos_menu` WHERE `title` LIKE '%tcp%'
```

More likely is a remaining entry in the extensions table which could be removed as follows:

```
DELETE FROM `jos_extensions` WHERE `name` = 'TCPDF'
```

Note: If necessary, update the prefix from "jos" in the above commands to the prefix you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to know how:
Here's the code:

```
SELECT * FROM `jos_menu` WHERE `title` LIKE '%tcp%'
```

Comment: This is simply a `select` query. Should it be removing or getting the data?